# Google Spreadsheet conditional formatting based on another cell Date

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Google spreedsheet with multiple columns and I am trying to apply the following two tasks but can't seem to figure out how to do so.

1. I have two columns C and D, where C present a date picker and D present a drop down list with two values [Complete - In Progress]. I am trying to figure out a way where any cell in column D will display (In Progress) if the corresponding cell date is less than or equal todays date
2. If column C date is 2 days ahead, change the whole row color to blue

Can the above be done using Google d=Any thoughts how I can complete any of the above two tasks? Thanks in advance for your time and efforts

Answer (score 1):

for example, if your Date is in C3 then like MKM said, the if function is your need

just paste this code into D3

```
=IF(C3<=TODAY();"in progress";"done")
```

i think that should do the trick, i tested your wish within this sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z6mwkxqc2NyLJsH16NFWyL01y0jGcKrNNtuYcJS5dNw/edit#gid=734876188
but i don't really get what you second question is about, hope this helps and answers this questions :)

PS.: may you can share your spreadsheet with us, so we might get a better understanding of your issue within google formatting ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on what your particular setup is, but I think using the IF statement may be what you're looking for.

For example:

C4 = Dec 10, 2017

D4 = Completed
D5 = In-Progress

E5 = IF(C4<[Specified Date], D5, D4)

Let's say [Specified Date] = Dec 8, 2017, then E5 would display In-Progress.
if the [Specified Date] = Dec 10, 2017 or higher E5 would display Completed.

For task 2:
You just need to add 2 Conditional Formatting for when cells are labelled as In-Progress and Completed.

I may have misunderstood your question as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help, for task 1 so D4 and D5 are two different rows under column D? If correct I apologize if I couldn't explain the setup correctly but in column D clicking any cell will open a drop down list with two values Completed or In-Progress, so D4 itself will have either Completed or IN-progress, make sense?